# Solution for rough walls after wallpaper removal

Tags: drywall, wallpaper

I was removing wallpaper from a very old apartment, (*Image belo*w)

Here are my thoughts for solving this:

1. Skim coat these rough walls and hope that it comes out smooth and even.
2. Use a thin drywall sheet and just put it over the rough walls which would need extra work on joints.

Both have pro and cons, I am not sure what to pick.

Has anyone dealt with such rough sheetrock or walls?

Are there any other solutions than mentioned above?

Any advice is a blessing to me!!
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: That looks like plaster, or even concrete, with a skim coat on it.

Comment: It is a plaster wall as it is hollow, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I prepare damaged plaster for painting?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-should-i-prepare-damaged-plaster-for-painting)

Comment: To me that looks like backer board, but the link to the duplicate for repair should answer the question.

Comment: Wallpaper seemed to do ok there.  New wallpaper?